# How to grey out a list item?

Tags: android, listview

How can I grey out one of my list item entirely, I dont mean set background to grey or sth. else.

```
    public View getView(Context context)
    {
        View view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.transfer_item, null);
        view.setBackgroundColor(_unmoveable ? 0xFF111111 : Color.TRANSPARENT);
        //view.setAlpha(0.5f);//? it says method did not exist ...
```

Comment: You can do as tim suggested or use `setTextColor` and `setBackgroundColor` to set both to gray and it will have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

put a View into the row on top of everything  else and set that View to your grey color.

Comment: I dont mean set background to grey or sth. else. And I also wanna know how to grey out LinearLayout.

Comment: that is why you need to make sure the grey view is on top (Z order wise) of  everything else. It will cover up everything and appear as just a grey block to the user.

Comment: I'm Sorry, I got confused. Why 'make sure grey view on the top' is important, let's just grey out the top single item instead.